# Magento - replacing all external css and javascript path in head

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to replace all external CSS and JS files path in Magento. What is the best way to do it? Using any observer?

For example, http://magentotest.localhost/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css would become http://magentotest.localhost/min/?f=skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css

Just trying the Minify library.

Comment: Maybe consider using the merge css and merge js options magento has, this way you will have to minify only 1 css file and 1 js file.

Comment: I dont know how merge works completely but i tried that option on another project in past, and it broke javascript functionality since may be the order of javascript files got changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get away with just changing the `skin_url` configuration from the admin; see System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Secure|Unsecure -> Base Skin URL.

In your case that would mean replacing
`{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/` with `{{unsecure_base_url}}min/?f=skin/`

If that doesn't work, one way of doing it would be to overwrite the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` block, the `getCssJsHtml` method; see `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php`